# Digital signatures (PDFs): how do they work, and what's the proper way tu use them?

Tags: security, pdf, identity, signature, digital

Please note that I'm not a developper (anymore), so a GUI-based solution would be a prefered way if it is possible (if it isn't, I'm ready to dive into whatever coding there needs to be).

And if you know about it, please include the different ways to manipulate them (Linux, Adobe Acrobat on Windows, USB...). I have a fully set up Acrobat account with my real identity. But on a daily basis I work on Linux (OpenSUSE Tumbleweed nowadays to be precise).

I have a very important medical document that I need to provide at State level, so I want to do it right, and do it right the first time.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you want? The title of your question indicates that you'd like some technical backgrounds. I'd propose reading the spec and other documents referred to from there. The main text of your question appears to be asking for a software recommendation. That strictly speaking is off-topic here, you may want to look at [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: Where exactly do I find "the spec and other documents referred to from there."? I don't know where to look. And fair point, I'll go over to sftwr reco for the second part.

Comment: PDF is a format (meanwhile) specified by the ISO - https://www.iso.org/standard/75839.html - but due to sponsorship of Adobe, Apryse, and Foxit you can get copies for free from the PDF association - https://www.pdfa-inc.org/product/iso-32000-2-pdf-2-0-bundle-sponsored-access/

Comment: Ok, I'll be honest: you're not helping me at all. I don't understand what I'm supposed to do with the links you've provided. Please tell me where the information I seek actually is (that is, digital signatures and their usage -- in simple terms).